# attempting to execute any command starting "rails" yields "Could not locate Gemfile"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, installation, rvm, gemfile

I am trying to install a new rails app.  I've already got several rails apps on my machine, all working fine.

```
$ rails new app
Could not locate Gemfile
```

Then I figured I'd run a trace to figure out what was going on, as you wouldn't expect to have a `Gemfile` at this point anyway, as typically the above command would create an entire new rails app in a directory named `app` with the `Gemfile` contained within that directory.

```
$ rails new app --trace
Could not locate Gemfile
```

So I tried to reinstall everything on my computer via this detailed guide:

http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html#gems

After the first 20 or so steps, I got to this command:

```
$ rake -v
Could not locate Gemfile
```

I assume something is off on my setup somewhere, but I can't see anything off.

Here are my rvm settings:

```
$ rvm version

rvm 1.18.10 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   jruby-1.6.7 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.1-p431 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p385 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p385 (found in /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385)
   (default)
   global
=> rails32
```

Here are the gems installed on my rails32 gemset

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
actionpack (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activemodel (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activerecord (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activeresource (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activesupport (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.2.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.7)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.21)
multi_json (1.6.1)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
railties (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.0)
rvm (1.11.3.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thor (0.17.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
```

Bundler Version

```
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.2.4
```

.gemrc file

```
$ cat ~/.gemrc
---
:backtrace: false
:benchmark: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- http://rubygems.org/
- https://rubygems.org
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

Everything seems to look fine, very frustrated, please help.

Comment: do you get the same error doing something like `rails -v` or `rails -h` ?

Comment: @Cluster Unfortunately, yes I get the same result.  Any ideas?

Comment: what about if you put `bundle exec` before some of these commands?

Comment: I just followed the instructions in that doc, the only difference is i used the latest ruby patch 392, and rails new worked fine.

Comment: @Cluster I just tried it again with patch 392, same result.  Also bundle exec yielded the same result.

Comment: At this point, unless you have a lot of gemsets/projects, I would blow away the rvm install. Either that or I would start digging into the commands themselves and start debugging from within the gems.

Comment: @Cluster thanks, I guess I'll do one of those two.  I have around 12 projects, so I'll likely start with the debugging, and then if I have to uninstall and reinstall RVM. I just wish the error gave me more context on why it's expecting a Gemfile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This errors happens only with commands prefixed with `bundle exec` or for `bundle install` without `Gemfile` in current dir.

My assumption is you might be running commands that enable `bundler`, check:

```
which rake
```

to find out what command is run.

Comment: Thank you!  I had aliased 'bundle exec rails' to 'rails' in my .bash_profile, your comment made it super easy to figure out what was going on.

Comment: This was also what I did. For those who want to override the alias just for that shell session, you can do: alias rails='rails'.

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle install
```

in the project directory fixed it for me. 
After that, I ran into this error:

> There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue.

And this was fixed with:

```
gem update bundler
```

Then my re-install of Ruby and Rails finally worked. It only took about four hours to make it work :-/