# Ruby on Rails /Gemfile not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I just installed RVM, Ruby 2.0, and Rails 3.2.15 on OS X Mountain Lion. Everytime I start a new Rails project I get the following:

```
➜  ~  rails new new_proj
  create
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/mailers
  create  app/models
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
  create  app/models/.gitkeep
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/.gitkeep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
  create  test/functional
  create  test/functional/.gitkeep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.gitkeep
  create  test/unit
  create  test/unit/.gitkeep
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install
/Gemfile not found
```

Here is the output of `which rails` and `which gem` and `which bundle`

```
➜  ~  which rails
/Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails
➜  ~  which gem
gem () {
typeset result
(
    typeset rvmrc
    rvm_rvmrc_files=("/etc/rvmrc" "$HOME/.rvmrc")
    if [[ -n "${rvm_prefix:-}" ]] && ! [[ "$HOME/.rvmrc" -ef "${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc" ]]
    then
        rvm_rvmrc_files+=("${rvm_prefix}/.rvmrc")
    fi
    for rvmrc in "${rvm_rvmrc_files[@]}"
    do
        [[ -s "${rvmrc}" ]] && source "${rvmrc}" || true
    done
    unset rvm_rvmrc_files
    command gem "$@"
) || result=$?
hash -r
return ${result:-0}
}

➜  ~  which bundle
/Users/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: try running bundle install manually. what happens?

Comment: Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed... oddly it works if I do it manually, which is not good if this is what I have to do all the time.

Comment: you will always have to do bundle install manually every time you update your gemfile(rails just do it automatically only once you create a new project :) ).

Comment: @sahildhankhar yes, i am aware of that, this is a NEW site, hence the rails new new_proj in my paste above :)

Comment: What is that `/` infront of Gemfile? Did you type that?

Comment: @stevanity nope, that was part of the output from `rails new new_proj` It stopped there, it didn't do the usual `bundle install` that comes from new projects

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please post output of `which rails` and `which bundle`.

Comment: @stevanity I updated the question with the output of that

Comment: Maybe related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15049676/2004045)?  Have you aliased the rails command?

Comment: Certainly not a rails ruby version dependency issue. Works file with same setup. Weird. Yes as @exbinary said please check for aliases. You seemed to have customized your terminal quite a bit. Maybe youve added in that alias somewhere along the way.

Comment: @stevanity - No aliases i just triple checked, my shell is just zsh with oh-my-zsh, I tried bash earlier just to see if it was related to weird shell issues as well and the same thing happens. So frustrating

Comment: @exbinary see above comment :)

Comment: Try making an empty dir and running the rails command from inside it: `mkdir new_proj; cd new_proj; rails new .`  If that works it may be a viable workaround until you figure out what's messed up?

Comment: Well, I narrowed down a bit more. Instead of RVM I used rbenv and everything went as planned, no issues. The issue is with rvm, I am not quite sure what it is though.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem.  Frustrating!  What is with this /Gemfile not found?  It's right there in the project folder?

Comment: @fatfrog I don't know what the issue is. I stopped using RVM and went with rbenv in the meantime. It makes no sense to me either and thereis literally no info about it

Comment: @JeffC are you using Mavericks?  I uninstalled and reinstalled using Rails 4 and it is working now.

Comment: Dont you think its weird that its saying `/Gemfile not found`? with that `/`?

Comment: @fatfrog, no mavericks here, i avoided it incase of issues for the first little while.

Comment: @stevanity very weird, it has to be an issue with rvm, like I said rbenv works fine for me the first try

Comment: What does `echo $BUNDLE_GEMFILE` tell you? I noticed the same thing and found that `$BUNDLE_GEMFILE` was set to `/Gemfile`. Calling `unset BUNDLE_GEMFILE` solved the issue for me, although I'm not sure why `$BUNDLE_GEMFILE` is getting set.

Comment: I also see "/Gemfile not found" but only when I use ruby 1.9.3-p448. I use RVM and when I switch to 1.9.3-p392 then everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I aliased my `'bundle exec'` command, and I was getting the same errors as you.  I removed the alias...BOOM! It works!